# DateTime parameter not working with EF core query

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I'm working with Azure SQL Server, .net core 3.1, EF core 5.0

So, I have this function in my repository, which receives a datetime as parameter:

```
 public IEnumerable<Channel> GetActiveChannels(DateTime date,int pageSize, int pageCounter)
        {
            try
            {
                IEnumerable<Channel> channels;

                var query = _context.Channel
                    .Include(channel => channel.ChannelStat
                    .OrderByDescending(stat => stat.RegisteredTime)
                    .Take(1))
                    .Where(channel => channel.RegisteredTime >= date)
                    .Skip(pageSize * pageCounter).Take(pageSize);
                channels = query.ToList();
                return channels;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

According to my logs, it gets correctly translated into sql as follows:

```
[Parameters=[@__date_0='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @__p_1='?' (DbType = Int32), @__p_2='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [t].[YTChannelId], [t].[BannerImageUrl], [t].[Bucket], [t].[Category], [t].[CategoryId], [t].[ChannelTitle], [t].[Country], [t].[CustomUrl], [t].[Description], [t].[Engagement], [t].[Keywords], [t].[Language], [t].[LastUpdate], [t].[PublishedAt], [t].[Reach], [t].[RegisteredTime], [t].[Thumbnail], [t0].[Id], [t0].[CommentCount], [t0].[Engagement], [t0].[HiddenSubscriberCount], [t0].[Reach], [t0].[RegisteredTime], [t0].[SubscriberCount], [t0].[VideoCount], [t0].[VideoReleased], [t0].[ViewCount], [t0].[YTChannelId]
FROM (
    SELECT [c].[YTChannelId], [c].[BannerImageUrl], [c].[Bucket], [c].[Category], [c].[CategoryId], [c].[ChannelTitle], [c].[Country], [c].[CustomUrl], [c].[Description], [c].[Engagement], [c].[Keywords], [c].[Language], [c].[LastUpdate], [c].[PublishedAt], [c].[Reach], [c].[RegisteredTime], [c].[Thumbnail]
    FROM [Channel] AS [c]
    WHERE [c].[RegisteredTime] >= @__date_0
    ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
    OFFSET @__p_1 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_2 ROWS ONLY
) AS [t]
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP(1) [c0].[Id], [c0].[CommentCount], [c0].[Engagement], [c0].[HiddenSubscriberCount], [c0].[Reach], [c0].[RegisteredTime], [c0].[SubscriberCount], [c0].[VideoCount], [c0].[VideoReleased], [c0].[ViewCount], [c0].[YTChannelId]
    FROM [ChannelStat] AS [c0]
    WHERE [t].[YTChannelId] = [c0].[YTChannelId]
    ORDER BY [c0].[RegisteredTime] DESC
) AS [t0]
ORDER BY [t].[YTChannelId], [t0].[RegisteredTime] DESC, [t0].[Id]
```

where

```
@__date_0='2020-09-07T09:35:47.8976418Z' (DbType = DateTime2), @__p_1='0' (DbType = Int32), @__p_2='10000'
```

The problem is that it is returning 0 rows, when I know for a fact that there are at least 200K that fulfill the criteria.

I don't know what to do here because I am passing a DateTime to the function, if I was passing a string I could accept that there are formatting issues. But shouldn't EF core translate this date to a suitable format that will be understood by the DBMS?

Also, if I just make `@__date_0='07-09-2020'` with the translated sql in my management studio, it gives me the answers I expect. So it looks like some sort of localization BS, but I still don't know how to correct it, since these dates will be generated automatically depending on when the call was made and the time part is very important to the outcome of the query. Plus of course I would also like to not be tied to a specific localization config. In case it matters all dates are in UTC.

Thanks in advance for the help

**EDIT to add the create tables requested**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Channel](
    [YTChannelId] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
    [ChannelTitle] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CustomUrl] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PublishedAt] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [Country] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [BannerImageUrl] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Thumbnail] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Keywords] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Engagement] [float] NULL,
    [Reach] [float] NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [Language] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Bucket] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [RegisteredTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Category] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CategoryId] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChannelStat](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [YTChannelId] [nvarchar](450) NULL,
    [ViewCount] [decimal](20, 0) NULL,
    [CommentCount] [decimal](20, 0) NULL,
    [SubscriberCount] [decimal](20, 0) NULL,
    [HiddenSubscriberCount] [bit] NULL,
    [VideoCount] [decimal](20, 0) NULL,
    [RegisteredTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Engagement] [float] NULL,
    [Reach] [float] NULL,
    [VideoReleased] [bit] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**EDIT to add 3 sample records**

```
YTChannelId BannerImageUrl  Bucket  Category    CategoryId  ChannelTitle    Country CustomUrl   Description Engagement  Keywords    Language    LastUpdate  PublishedAt Reach   RegisteredTime  Thumbnail   Id  CommentCount    Engagement  HiddenSubscriberCount   Reach   RegisteredTime  SubscriberCount VideoCount  VideoReleased   ViewCount   YTChannelId
UC__03yLhZqBGyW2mQBtRvrQ    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    TBD NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2020-07-15 14:54:07.3633333 NULL    NULL    2020-07-15 14:54:07.3633333 NULL    3B6BF961-0E43-4824-A93F-2E1C102A8745    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2020-07-15 20:35:05.9633333 NULL    NULL    0   NULL    UC__03yLhZqBGyW2mQBtRvrQ
UC__08GrddvOiUgC8_AU1FQA    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    TBD NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2020-07-15 14:59:42.9300000 NULL    NULL    2020-07-15 14:59:42.9300000 NULL    C9FD745F-6C92-4AE4-8E46-44EAD9FE8DBF    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2020-07-15 20:35:05.9633333 NULL    NULL    0   NULL    UC__08GrddvOiUgC8_AU1FQA
UC__1aTDqHjrbAOHcfne7kuQ    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    TBD NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2020-07-15 15:02:59.0100000 NULL    NULL    2020-07-15 15:02:59.0100000 NULL    26F6C6D0-B545-4624-8174-B0EAE620004C    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2020-07-15 20:35:05.9633333 NULL    NULL    0   NULL    UC__1aTDqHjrbAOHcfne7kuQ
```

**EDIT to add user options**

```
Set Option  Value
textsize    2147483647
language    us_english
dateformat  mdy
datefirst   7
lock_timeout    -1
quoted_identifier   SET
arithabort  SET
ansi_null_dflt_on   SET
ansi_warnings   SET
ansi_padding    SET
ansi_nulls  SET
concat_null_yields_null SET
isolation level read committed snapshot
```

and `select GETDATE()` returns `2020-09-08 11:50:27.287`

**EDIT to add the watch screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221155/discussion-on-question-by-gris-datetime-parameter-not-working-with-ef-core-query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your C# code is passing in 7th September. All of the data in your database is before that date - so it isn't returned. Everything is working as expected.

But why does `@__date_0='07-09-2020'` work then? Well, that is due to your settings - specifically `dateformat  mdy`. That tells SQL Server to treat that string as MDY. So you *think* you are passing 7th September - but you are *actually* passing 9th July (which "works" - since your data in 15th July **is** after 9th July).

Comment: indeed it was a localization problem, only that it was a "mental" localization issue =P
Thanks again for taking the time